# Dynamically generated field in nested form added twice Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have two models, the first is grants the second is specs.  Specs has two fields ineligibility and eligibility and is nested into grants.  I have mostly everything set up fine but I need help modifying the JQuery because every time I click "add an ineligibility", an eligibility is also added. It doesn't show up on the form but it does show up as a blank bullet on my show view.  When I go back to edit the form I now see the blank field for eligibility.  If I enter new text into eligibility both fields save the correct text.  I want to be able to add one field without automatically adding the other.  My jQuery and helper code comes from  Railscasts PRO #196 Nested Model Form.  I'm new to rails and especially jQuery so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
jQuery ->
$('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

and the helper method:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(name.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to share my solution for anyone who might be trying to do the same thing.  The mistake I made was thinking that I could have several fields in each model but only save one of those fields to the database.  But every time I add a field it saves the whole record with all the other fields even if they are blank.  This is why every time I add an eligibility I also get an blank ineligibility field.  The solution is to break up the model and create a new model for every field needed.

Since my real goal is just to have bulleted lists of eligibility and ineligibility I came up with two other solutions that simply handle formatting.  The first is to use a rich text editor and the other is to use .gsub to add in the formatting after the fact.  For example:

```
<p>
  <strong>Eligibility:</strong>
  <%= (@grant.eligibility).gsub(/[=+~]/, '=' => '<ul>','~' => '</ul>', '+' => '<li/>').html_safe %> 
</p>
```